# Cypress, loop till response of api call has expected value

Tags: cypress

Im making an api call with cypress. This apis returns status of operation happening server side. Sample response `{'status':'13'}`. This means job completed 13%. I have to wait till I get status as 100 before performing other operations.

```
...
cy.request(getStatusUrl)
.then(response => {
    console.log(response.body.status);
});
...
```

I have keep polling getStatusUrl till status comes as "100".

How do I get the value of `response.body.status` out of `then{...}` to use in a loop?

Comment: You can't use a loop here since it's synchronous (actually you may think of something using awaits) so I'd suggest using recursion. I left a response down below.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```js
function pollProgress(url, done) {
  cy.request(url)
    .then(response => {
      const progress = response.body.status;

      // Poll every 500ms until progress reaches 100%
      setTimeout(() => {
        if (progress < 100) {
          pollProgress(url, done);
        } else {
          done({ status: 'OK' });
        }
      }, 500);
    })
    .catch(() => {
      done({ status: 'ERROR' })
    })
}

...

new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
  pollProgress(getStatusUrl, ({ status }) => {
    if (status == 'OK') ? resolve() : reject();
  });
})
.then(() => {
  // it's 100% here if there's no error
})
```

Comment: Thank you. Also found Search Results cypress-wait-until npm package, which can be used in situations like this.

Comment: @Dileep17 Yep. I bet the package does kind of the same. I'd not include an extra package for that.